# Infinite loop when calling many on custom Parser

Tags: haskell, alternative-functor, some-and-many

I'm loosely following Stephen Diehl's [Write you a Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/index.html) for implementing my own parser. However, I'm stuck at a point where calls to `many` and `some` will go into an infinite loop. I have pinpointed the loop to my parser's `fmap` function using `trace`, but I can't figure out why the loop is occurring. Looking at [the source for `some` and `many`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#some), it seems that the only other functions that are called are `<*>` (through `liftA2)`, `pure` and `<|>`; I've tried putting calls to `trace` on all of those, but none of those show up on stdout.

The essential parts of my parser look like this:

```
data Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }

item :: Parser Char
item = trace "item" Parser $ \s ->
  case s of
    [] -> []
    (x:xs) -> pure (x, xs)

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Parser p) = trace "fmap" Parser $ fmap (first f) . p

instance Applicative Parser where
  (Parser p1) <*> (Parser p2) = trace "<*>" Parser $ 
    \s1 -> [(f x, s3) | (f, s2) <- p1 s1, (x, s3) <- p2 s2]
  pure x = trace "pure" Parser $ \s -> pure (x, s)


instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = trace "empty" Parser $ const mempty
  (Parser p1) <|> (Parser p2) = trace "<*>" Parser $ \s -> case p1 s of
    [] -> p2 s
    x  -> x
```

Calling `many` or `some` shows the following output:

```
> runParser (many item) "abcd"
item
fmap
fmap
fmap
(and so forth)
```

As far as I can tell, my functions are correctly implemented. Why would this infinite loop on `fmap` occur?

Comment: After reading the duplicate question, changing `(Parser p1) <*> (Parser p2)` to `(Parser p1) <*> p2` fixed the issue.